# About the definition of mean square convergence.

Tags: probability

A sequence of random variables $X_n$ is said to converge to $X$ in mean square if
$$\mathbb{E}\left((X_n-X)^2\right) \rightarrow 0 \ \ \mathrm{as\ } n\rightarrow \infty$$.

I understand what expected value is when I have a single random variable with a known pdf, and I know how to find pdfs of sums of random variables if I know how they are dependent. But in this definition, I don't know if $X_n$ is independent of $X$, so I don't know what pdf to take the expected value over.

There seems to be not enough information for this definition to mean anything.

Comment: The expected value can exist even without a pdf. The most obvious example is for discrete random variables (for which the above definition of mean-square convergence is still true) but also, for example:
$$X=-1\text{ with probability }1/2,\ X=Y\text{ with probability }1/2$$
where $Y$ is a uniform $(0,1)$ random variable. The random variable $X$ has an expected value of $-1/4$, but this isn't something you can calculate with a pdf.

Comment: Expectations are defined in a much broader sense than for random variables with a pdf.

Comment: I don't understand how to compute expectations without a pdf.

Say all random variables are nonconstant and continuous, with pdfs. For example, $X_n \sim N(0,\frac{1}{2^n})$. The pdfs are going uniformly to $X \sim N(0,1)$, so I should have mean convergence too, but I don't know what to make of $\mathbb{E}(Xn-X)^2$.